Intersection of product of cycles with graph equals intersection of pushforward
I'm trying to work out the proof of Lemma 2.5 in these notes: fix $A, B \in H_\bullet (X)$ of degrees adding up to $n$, the dimension of $X$. Let $f : X \to X$ be a continuous map, and let $\Gamma(f) \subset X\times X$ be its graph. Then $[\Gamma(f)] \cdot (A \times B) = (-1)^{\deg A} f_* A \cdot B$.
Here's how I think the proof should go: let $D_X (A)$ denote the Poincare dual of $A$, and let $p : X \times X \to X$ be projection onto the second factor. Then we have the following facts:

$B = p_* (A \times B)$,
$[X] = p_* [X \times X]$,
if $(1,f) : X \to X \times X$ is the map whose image is $\Gamma(f)$, then $f_* = p_* \circ (1,f)_*$,
$[\Gamma(f)] = (1,f)_* [X]$,
$[\Gamma(f)] \cdot (A \times B) = [\Gamma(f|_A)] \cdot (A \times B)$. I'm not sure how to make this last rigorous unless $A$ is represented by a submanifold.

By the projection formula and naturality of $D$, we have
\begin{align}
f_* A \cdot B
&= [X] \cap (D_X(f_* A) \cup D_X(B)) \\
&= p_* ([X \times X] \cap (p^* D_X (f_* A) \cup D_{X \times X} (A \times B) )) \\
&= p_* ([X \times X] \cap (p^* D_X (p_* (1,f)_* A) \cup D_{X \times X} (A \times B) )) \\
&= p_* ([X \times X] \cap (D_{X \times X} ((1,f)_* A) \cup D_{X \times X} (A \times B) )) \\
&= p_* ([\Gamma(f|_A)] \cdot (A \times B)) \\
&= p_* ([\Gamma(f)] \cdot (A \times B))
\end{align}
Now something must have gone wrong, because there's no sign here! What's the catch?
